# How do I create a customized button for use in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net, button, expression-blend

Suppose I have a Microsoft Expression Blend. Is it possible to create a custom control (such as a button) in MSE Blend and then import it to visual basic 2010?

For example, I want to create a custom shape button (different from what is available in the toolbox in VB2010) (like for example a pen-shaped button) in MSE Blend. Can I import it to VB2010 to be used with Windows Forms Projects? If yes, how?

(Added)

If Expression Blend designs cannot be used in windows forms, how then can I create a custom-shaped button in windows forms?

Your response will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Expression Blend produces XAML based contents and you cannot use it with windows forms.

Comment: I see.. I just thought it could be used in windows forms because it can be connected with VB2010. Since that is the case, then how can I create a custom-shaped button in windows forms? I'll be revising my question. thanks by the way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WPF controls created in Expression Blend in a Winforms project.

You use the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control to host the WPF control. [Here's](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DanielMoth/Use-WPF-from-Windows-Forms-projects-in-Visual-Studio-2008) a Channel9 video demonstrating how to do this.

There are some [limitations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx) to interop between WPF and Winforms but none will likely stop you creating and using a custom button.

Otherwise you could create the control in Winforms but it will probably not be as easy. You have a few options:

- Create a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) to 'draw' your custom shape. The [`Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx) property might help creating a custom shape and you could just use an image of the look you want.
- Use a custom class (possibly inheriting from `Button`) where you do all the controls drawing (in the `Paint` event) and handle all the mouse events yourself. Not an easy task.